# Independent C library or function (on Linux) to programmatically generate a self-signed certificate

Tags: certificates, linux, c, self-signed

Is there a simple C library or function to programmatically generate a self-signed certificate in C on Ubuntu?  Of course, one can execute a simple `system("....")` call to execute a CLI. I am looking for a native, small, stand-alone library just for this purpose with possibly added functionality but not with the full-weight of TLS implementations such as openssl, boringssl, mbedTls, etc.

Comment: You're running Ubuntu but you can't just link to the OpenSSL library?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Is there a product/service that does X?" questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a simple C library or function to programmatically generate a self-signed Certificate in C on Ubuntu?

One that isn't OpenSSL on a base Ubuntu system? No.

> I am looking for a native small stand-alone library just for this purpose with possibly added functionality but not with the full-weight of TLS implementations such as openssl, boringssl, mbedTls, etc.

It may be possible to isolate some of the code and make it into a standalone method somehow, but I'd discourage this route. It's unlikely that such a tool or library exists for this task on its own.

Use a known, maintained TLS library for this. Even if it will ever only be generating self-signed certs.

Comment: I agree with @Pedro.  Creating self-signed certificates involves ASN.1, X.509, and DER encoding.  See the answer by Marteen Bodewes at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40157/parsing-of-x-509-certificates for why you want to stick with with the tried and true for this.

Comment: @Pedro  Will wait for a few more responses if there is nothing available, will accept as answer.